# How to identify webview vs. ios native

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am working on a project that needs to identify between webview vs. ios native code. Is there a way to tell by looking at the apps which method an app is using? For example. Facebook, Yelp, Uber

Comment: Are you asking for a way to identify which method is being used through a programming language or by looking at the apps in question?

Comment: By looking at the apps